# Multiple nodes with same IP

Tags: router

At my current office over the years people have added more and more hub/switch/routers to the network without proper settings. I am thinking since most if not all of these devices have their default IP settings then there are many nodes with the IP 192.168.1.1 or .0.1. Although, only one main router that is directly connected to the modem has DHCP on.

My question is does this duplicate IP situation present a problem to the network? Could it slow down the network? Thank you very much.

Comment: before You do anything, get rid of the hubs! There are unattended switches that you should use instead.

Comment: What is unattended switch? The hub was probably used because it has a high number of ports

Comment: Seems like I was tired when I wrote that, I was looking for the word **Unmanaged** Switch. You just don't want hubs in your network, they are the root of lots and lots of problems. If You do not believe me, listen to him: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9yYqNqTNnqI

Answer (score 0):

If 2 devices have the same IP on the same network, that will **not** slow down the network.
There will be an IP conflict and the device first connected to the network will work and the second one will not be able to connect to the network.

One of the reason that your network might be slow is because of hubs.

The first thing You want to do is throw out all of the hubs in the trash and buy some Unmanaged swtiches instead.

Hubs are just bad.
For explanation watch this video, or at least the first 8 minutes of it:
https://youtu.be/9yYqNqTNnqI

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Well in my case the switches and routers that have the same IP do work in the sense that all devices connected to them can get IP through DHCP on main router. Although frequently there is a slow down and eventually I just have to reboot the main router for everything to work again. I am trying to find out if that same IP issue could cause this, but I think according to you it doesn't? OK will learn more about Unmanaged Switches. Thank you

Comment: @rabbid - The problems that You described are most likely caused by hubs. By the way, are your problems still present? If yes, feel confident to ask. If your problems are solved, than if I helped, You can accept this as an answer. If You solved it with another method, than You should answer your own question with the solution.